# Data from XML Infile MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, load-data-infile

**Helly Everyone,**

i got a machine that produces logfiles, which i want to import into my MySQL-Database.
These Logfiles are XML-Files and looking like :

```
<LoetProtokoll>
<LoetProtElement LoetProtElementTyp="LfdNr" LoetProtElementName="Laufende Nummer" LoetProtElementIstwert="2935" />
<LoetProtElement LoetProtElementTyp="Produkt" LoetProtElementName="Produktname" LoetProtElementIstwert="" />
<LoetProtElement LoetProtElementTyp="Traeger" LoetProtElementName="Werkzeugtraeger" LoetProtElementIstwert="" />
```

Im interested in importing the last attribute of **LoetProtokollElement** :

**LoetProtElementIstwert="..."**

and im struggling with finding the right way to do it with the ***Load XML Infile - MySQL-Syntax***.

Ist there any way to do it this way, or do i need to find another way to import these attributes.

Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Greetings Marcel

Answer (score 0):

To import the data in xml file into the MySQL table, you can use this statement:

```
mysql> LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'FILENAME.xml'
->   INTO TABLE table_name
->   ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<LoetProtElement>';
```

Take a look [at here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for ur advice, i already got this conclusion, but i dont want to import all attributes to a seperate column, instead i just want to import the last attribute LoetProtElementIstwert=... to a table in lines. Is there a way to edit the load xml infile syntax this way or do i have to use the table ur commands produces to go foward?